How to eliminate Lag when connecting to Ubuntu Server via xrdp and Remmina?
I have set up a VPS running Ubuntu Server 24.04. The plan is to have it run as a terminal server allowing multi-session RDP Connections from my teams local Linux devices.
I’ve installed XRDP along with Linux-Mint as the OS for the Remote Desktop for each session. However I noticed that when I am connecting through my laptop via Remmina to the server to any user account the performance is acceptable. However when I am connecting via a standard work desktop from the office, the performance drops significantly. Dragging and resizing windows looks like it’s going by 1fps in a wave like motion. Launching a new process has a delay of 5-10seconds.
I have base configurations for xrdp. My Remmina connection settings are also default. So I don’t fully understand why there is such a significant difference between my laptop connecting to the server and the work desktops doing so.
Can someone provide me with any hints as to how I can fix this or where I can look for any potential issues that may be causing this? I would be very thankful for any and all assistance.
I’ve attempted to resolve this, however could not find anything that could help me without switching to VNC instead of RDP.
My VPS runs on the following specs:
2.4Ghz
10GBps bandwidth
SSD storage
12vCPU
32GB ram.
Please let me know what else I can provide to assist me in resolving this matter!
